# C# delete column from datatable where all values are zero

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to delete columns from datatable where all rows have 0 for value. Or in other words, where sum is 0.

```
1 2  5   99.9 442.25 221 0
1 2 77.7 889  898     55 0
9 0 66   42    55      0 0
```

In this example, last column should be removed.

How to do this?

Comment: Be more specific with your question

Comment: "Or in other words, where sum is 0." That's not only "the other words", that's quite a different thing (think of a column with some positive values and some negative values).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight they shouldn't be negative. But let's ignore other words.

Comment: You do not normally delete *columns* from database tables: it is a schema operation, not a data operation; it is very rare for your program to need to do something like that. Removing rows with all columns set to zero, on the other hand, is a lot more common.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight its C# datatable, not database dable

Comment: @elninho Oh, that makes a lot more sense :)

Comment: What data access technology do you use? ADO.NET? LINQ-to-SQL?

Comment: @Serge I'm getting datatable, which is result of stored procedure on SQL Server, via System.Data.SqlClient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DataTable dt;
int dataWidth = 5;  //use a loop or something to determine how many columns will have data
bool[] emptyCols = new bool[datawidth];  //initialize all values to true
foreach(Row r in dt)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < dataWidth; i++)
    {
        if(r[i].Contents != 0))
           emptyCols[i] = false;
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < emptyCols.Length; i++)
{
     if(emptyCols[i])
        dt.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

I haven't tested that, but I have done similar stuff with excel columns. The basic logic is there, I don't know if all of my increments or row numbering is exactly correct. I believe most of the functions I used are available as well.

Answer (score 1):

First:

```
protected Boolean IsColumnZero(DataTable dt, string columnName)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) 
        if ((int)row[columnName] != 0) return false;        
    return true;
}
```

and then You can:

```
    //create table
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("caliber", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("barrel", typeof(int));

    table.Rows.Add(762, 0);
    table.Rows.Add(556, 0);
    table.Rows.Add(900, 0);

    //delete zero value columns
    List<string> columnsToDelete = new List<string>();

    foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns) 
        if (IsColumnZero(table, column.ColumnName)) 
            columnsToDelete.Add(column.ColumnName);

    foreach (string ctd in columnsToDelete) table.Columns.Remove(ctd);

    //show results
    GridView1.DataSource = table;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```